# TextRank using BM25F

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, whoosh

I am trying to incorporate BM25F in textrank, I found out a scoring module http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scoring.html, but am unable to implement it. Has anyone incorporated this in textrank? How to go by this?

I incorporated Textrank with cosinesimilarity in python but am thinking of extending it to BM25F.